# Prove that $lim_{x\to 0}$ f(x) DNE

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, limits, convergence-divergence

Let f : $\mathbb{R} → \mathbb{R}$ be defined by

f(x) = {cos($1\over{x}$) if x $\neq$ 0, 
        0 if x = 0}

Prove that $lim_{x\to 0}$ f(x) does not exist.

I would like to use the following theorem: $\lim_{x\to a}$f (x) = L if and only if:

For every sequence $x_k$ in $D_f$ \ {a}, if $x_k$ → a, then f($x_k$) → L.

My solution: If there did exist a number L such that $lim_{x\to 0}$f(x) = L, then f($x_k$) $\to L$ for all sequences $x_k \to 0$. But as $x_k$ $\to 0$ from the left and the right, f($x_k$) does not converge to one distinct number L (it oscillates). Thus, it is not the case that f($x_k$) $\to L$ for all sequences $x_k$ $\to 0$. Therefore, $lim_{x\to 0}$ f(x) does not exist.

Any corrections or suggestions to improve this proof would be appreciated!

Comment: For $1/x=k\pi$, $\cos(1/x)=(-1)^k$, which is $1$ for even $k$ and $-1$ for odd $k$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're on the right track, maybe you can craft two sequences $(u_n)_n$ and $(v_n)_n$ so that $\lim_{n\to \infty} u_n = \lim_{n\to \infty} v_n = 0$ **but** $\lim_{n\to \infty} f(u_n) \ne \lim_{n\to \infty} f(v_n)$ ?

Hint : You can craft $u$ and $v$ so that $\forall n \in \mathbb{N}, f(u_n)=0,f(v_n) = 1$

Comment: How can f($u_n$) and f($v_n$) equal distinct numbers if it oscillates infinitely many times as $u_n$ and $v_n$ approach 0?

Comment: What about $\forall n , u_n = {1\over n.2\pi}$ ? Do we have $\lim_{n\to\infty} u_n = 0 $ ? what about $f(u_n)$ ?
As you can see, even if it oscilates 'more and more' as we approach 0, we can still 'extract' a sequence that always have the same image by $f$

Comment: f($u_n$) would be 1. Then my goal would be to find f($v_n$) such that f($v_n$) doesn't equal 1, like 0 perhaps?

Comment: Then we would have two distinct limits, thus the limit not existing?

Comment: Yes that's right, now what sequence can you think of that converge to 0 but its image by f is always 0 ?

Comment: Hm, I will think about that. Hold on.

Comment: Well I thought 1/(npi/2) would work...

Comment: You're almost there John ! If $cos(x)=0$ then $x={\pi \over 2} + n.\pi$

Comment: Does f(x) converge to .804 or am I putting it in my calculator incorrectly?

Comment: Do not trust your calculator xD $f({2\over n.\pi})$ has no limit.

Comment: I put in cos(1/((pi+2pix/2)))

Comment: John, put your calculator down and think about what it means that $cos(x) = 0$. Then from there, try and build $v_n$.

Comment: It means that x = pi/2 + pi(n) for some n. Then cos(1/x) would converge to 0 if you took the reciprocal of x?

Comment: Now it's working on my calculator. Good call on putting my calculator down for a minute :)

Comment: Ok so $cos(x) = 0 \Rightarrow x = {\pi\over2} + k\pi $. This is the same as $cos({1\over x}) = 0 \Rightarrow x = {1\over{\pi\over2} + k\pi} $. We need to find $v_n$ so $f(v_n) = cos({1\over v_n}) = 0$ so we can pick $v_n = {1\over{\pi\over2} + n\pi}$

Comment: Right, so the fact that we have constructed two sequences which both converge to 0 but when you take f of them, the fact that they have different limits suffices, correct?

Comment: Indeed, it is what your theorem said : If $lim_{x\to a} f(x) = L$ then for every sequence $x_k$ so that $lim_{k\to\infty}x_k=a$ we have $lim_{k\to\infty}f(x_k)=L$ . 

Here we found two sequences that converges to 0 but have different images by $f$ so it proves $f$ has no limit in $0$

Comment: Alright, thought so just making sure. Thanks for all the help

Comment: No    problem John  =)